# Rectangular Nesting - Convergence to optimal solution using Simulated Annealing

Tags: matlab, optimization, geometry, computational-geometry, geometry-surface

I'm using **Simulated Annealing** for Rectangular Nesting problem. I'm able to get good results, but the solution i got is DISCRETE. Even global optimum is not always obtained.

**Problem Description:**

**Objective** - 
To minimize the length of the infinite sheet (Width is constant) by changing the order in which parts are placed.

**Problem i Face:**

The output Results i get are DISCRETE(only 15 possible utilization %) instead of ANALOG (as there is 11!*2^11 possible solution -> We expect the results to be analog)

**Path traveled by SA** - MATLAB output [image]

**Results I expect** Generated for a different problem using the same SA code i used for this problem
[image]

Reason i get a DISCRETE output can be seen from following image. There could be many possibility of sequences giving same length 55.

*Efficiency* calculated from **Maximum Length**
[image]

I presume i could solve the problem if i change the way of calculating utilization% like this.

*Efficiency* calculated from **Boundary cut Length**
[image]

Even though i figured out how to solve the problem, i don't know how to find the Boundary Cut AREA in order to find the efficiency. Anybody has a way to find the area under the red line? I need to avoid using `Image Processing Toolbox`

**FYI:** 
Rectangles are stored as x,y distance of the bottom-left position from Origin of each rectangle. i have the corresponding length, breadth values in another variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, how to find **Boundary-Cut Area** *without* using `Image Processing Toolbox`. I would like to post this as an answer for others having similar problem. Better solutions are also welcome.

**Logic for placing of parts:**

Place the parts from `Left-> Right`, till the `Right most end` , then go to `Left end` and place the next part over the previous part, move `Right` and so on.

**Solution for finding Boundary Cut Area:**

I just create a Single Dimension Matrix whose length equal to the width of the sheet (In the above screen shot -> 200) By Default, i set their values to `zero`.

```
boundaryLength = zeros(sheetWidth+1,1);   
% sheetWidth+1 because matlab starts from the index 1 while my range is from 0-200
```

Each time i place a part, i assign the range of values i.e from its `xDist` of the bottom left position till `xDist` of the bottom right position to `yDist` value of the top line.

```
for i = 1:numberOfParts
    boundaryLength(xDist(i)+1:xDist(i)+width(Index(i))) = yDist(i)+ height(Index(i));
end

% Index is the order in which i place the part. 
% Here in the above screenshot, my index value is [8, 2, 4, 11, 7, 5, 6, 10, 1, 9, 3]
```

Now i have found out the maximum occupied length of every pixel throughout the sheet width. To find the area, i need to find the sum of the vector `boundaryLength`

```
boundaryArea = sum(boundaryLength);
```

**Boundary-Cut Utilization** for an example:
[image]